# An error occured while attempting to perform a type cast

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to transfer data from datalake to datawarehouse. I have a derived column in the process in my SSIS package that takes an `id` column of type string and converts into a uniqueidentifier, the job is a daily run.

But it failed for us one day with the error

> An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast

Any light on this would help in identifying the issue.

[image]

I have tried looking into the other runs, but couldn't find any issues.

Comment: Sql does not mean a database product on this website tag the database product you are using... i assume you use SQL Server because you mentioned SSIS

Comment: Redirect your rows to a multicast and enable dataviewer. This would give you the failing rows.

Comment: Add an error output for the derived column to check the value causing the error

Comment: The execution report should tell you which row it failed on.